# Maven release update policy

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I see that the `releases` [setting](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-settings/settings.html#class_releases) in the maven settings has got an `updatePolicy` as the `snapshots` [setting](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-settings/settings.html#class_snapshots) has. I was always under the impression released artifacts won't/shouldn't change, so there can't ever be a question of update policy when it comes to `releases`. Or am I wrong?

Does `releases` having an `updatePolicy` mean that `releases` behave the same way as `snapshots` in this regard? Or will that setting not work (in which case the documentation needs to be updated) with the `releases` at all?

Not that I ever tried it myself, but it sounds like a terrible idea should the `updatePolicy` work with `releases`; so I wanted to know if it would work in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does releases having an updatePolicy mean that releases behave the same way as snapshots in this regard? Or will that setting not work (in which case the documentation needs to be updated) with the releases at all?

Some maven managed repository allows to overwrite release artifacts, so to match with it you can configure your `settings.xml` (this would be in very rare case)

Comment: So you mean, to NOT want this `release` artifact overwrite to happen, we should always make sure the `updatePolicy` is set to `never` for `releases` in my `settings.xml` (`daily` being the default which would be undesirable to say the least in my case)?

Comment: if your environment is expecting updates in releases then you should configure it explicitly to update them, not otherwise (I don't think updating release is a common case)

Comment: My case is that I don't ever want release updates to happen (even if there ever was one), so I think I was right in that the `updatePolicy` should be set to `never` for `releases` in my case. I'm surprised with the lack of any warning about this behavior in the official docs., though.

Comment: also make sure where you push your releases that maven managed repository, restrict override there as well

Comment: That makes sense too. Cheers.