# Why doesn't mvn dependency:purge-local-repository fetch the same dependencies as mvn install does?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, dependency-management

I don't understand why an errors occurs when I invoke `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DreResolve=true` and it doesn't when I invoke `mvn install`. I experienced failures of `dependency:purge-local-repository`, but sucess of `mvn install`? How could this happen if the build succeeded once (i.e. all dependencies could be fetched from somewhere), but not in re-resolution of `dependency:purge-local-repository`. Do I suffer from a general misunderstanding?

Issues occured with maven 3.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

`mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` will remove the project dependencies from the local repository, and optionally re-resolve them

so in this case it will redownload all the dependencies that project needs after purging them from local repository

while `mvn install` will just update dependencies based on policy specified in `settings.xml`

most of the time it will just download the dependencies which aren't available in your local repository (or needing an update based on your policy in `settings.xml`)

Comment: I assumed re-resolution in the question (is the default value and otherwise the question wouldn't make sense). Question: So, does the re-resolution work different from the update? Assume I don't have a `settings.xml` which options/mechanisms/precedences influence the failures I'm experiencing?

Comment: if you don't have settings.xml then it reads from maven's default settings.xml (global) then, now what is your exact new question ?

Comment: I meant an individual/customized `settings.xml`. I'm sure that not **all** settings in the global `settings.xml` will influence the retrieval of dependencies and wanted to know which are those that do, what the "policy" is expressed in maven settings you're referring to in your answer.

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683994/maven-release-update-policy/24684633#24684633)